# Why the core migrate modules won't be enough?

Tags: 8, migrations

I've seen that Drupal 8 comes with 2 core migration modules; These are "Migrate", and "Migrate Drupal".

My question: if we want to migrate SQL from a Drupal 7 site to our brand new Drupal 8 site, why aren't these two enough, and why do we also need to download the module [Drupal Upgrade](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_upgrade)? Wasn't there a plan to make the process free of any contrib modules whatsoever?

Comment: This may be a time-sensitive answer (it may get out of date in the future), but I don't see why this warrants downvotes.  It is a confusing aspect of what got into D8 versus what didn't.

Comment: As you can read that is just the UI. You should not need anything for migration but drush. Also Migrate is the API and Migrate Drupal is a module that implements migrate api for Drupal core(6,7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Drupal Upgrade](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_upgrade) page, which includes this:

> UI and drush command for core upgrades from D6 or D7 to D8 - **the plan
>   is for this to live in contrib for now and ultimately bring the UI
>   into core** (a decision will be made shortly before RC whether it will
>   make it into 8.0.0) and the drush command into Drush itself

So since it is still in active development, it has **not yet been added to core**. In other words: consider this as a "didn't make it to D8 CORE  **yet**".

Refer to the issue about "[Plan for Drupal Upgrade 8.x-1.0 release](https://www.drupal.org/node/2622498)" for what, IMHO, is probably the best place to see how this is going to evolve in the (near?) future ... Like will it make it into Drupal 8.1 "core"?

**Note**: The module's Project page ***title*** is "Drupal Upgrade", while de module's project page URL ends with "migrate_upgrade" (and not with something like "drupal_upgrade").

Comment: They also mentioned this at a Drupal con. (LA or Barcelona, can't remember exactly)

Answer (score 6):

This is asking two questions. 1) What do I need beside core for migrating to D8 from D7. 2) What is [Drupal Upgrade](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_upgrade).

1. If all your fields and data in D7 are core fields, then you do not need anything from contrib. If you have non-core fields i.e. userpoints, then you'll need source and destination migrate plugins for those non-core field types. Same applies to any non-core Drupal data.
2. Core does not currently have a UI. It is in the works, but until then if you want a UI, use [Drupal Upgrade](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_upgrade). Or you can use drush and [migrate_tools](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_tools). Mike Ryans's [blog post](http://mikeryan.name/blog/mikeryan/drupal-8-migration-all-modules) provides a  break-down of the current module landscape for D8 migrations.

Lastly, if you are trying to suck in strait SQL data, the above mentioned blog post provides some suggestions.

> In migrate_plus, open up migrate_example/README.txt and it will guide
>   you through the basics of implementing SQL-based migrations. It's
>   simpler than you think!

Comment: As far as I can remember all my fields in the relevant site are core... Is there a specific guide you might recommend for douing core-level only upgrade ?

Comment: the module "drupal upgrade" is really called "migrate upgrade".

Comment: @tenken : I disagree ... refer to the **Note** in my answer for details ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens No, the note is incorrect in my opinion. It's not a `namespace` it's the modules `machine_name`. You `drush en MACHINE_NAME`. The project name, or the `name` field in the `info.yml` file (https://www.drupal.org/node/2000204) is merely an _administrative name_ just like an administrative block title name; it's not the true name of the content. The true name of a module is its machine name, which by convention is also a namespace.

Comment: OK, I corrected my note now to avoid using whatever term I should use. My point (in my note) is to make it clear that there is a huge discrepancy between the title and the end of the URL (though usually they are close to identical).